# Backend application to bookmark GitHub repository

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

The backend part has the following purposes.

- An endpoint that takes a search term and returns a list of repositories.
- An endpoint that allows bookmarking a repository by its id.
- An endpoint to get all bookmarked repositories
- An endpoint to remove a bookmark.

I have written the code for the [application](https://github.com/mnaveenchand/conradchallenge) using NodeJS and Express. The application is working well. I would like to have a code review for code quality and suggestions for improvements.

```js
const express = require('express');
const timeout = require('express-timeout-handler');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config();
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());


let options = {
    timeout: 3000,
    onTimeout: function(req, res) {
      res.status(503).send('Service unavailable. Please retry.');
    },
    onDelayedResponse: function(req, method, args, requestTime) {
      console.log(`Attempted to call ${method} after timeout`);
    },
    disable: ['write', 'setHeaders', 'send', 'json', 'end']
  };

app.use(timeout.handler(options));


app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server Listening on port ${port}`));

const listrepositoriesRoutes = require('./routes/repositories.route');
const bookmarksRoutes = require('./routes/bookmarks.route');
const authentication = require('./basic_auth/auth');
app.use('/userauth', authentication);
app.use('/listallrepos', listrepositoriesRoutes);
app.use('/bookmarks', bookmarksRoutes);
```

Comment: Welcome to CR! There doesn't really appear to be much substantial code in the question itself for review--this is a pretty standard set of Node imports and route boilerplate. You can also [omit some superfluous language](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).